# How to access Jenkins Dashboard on Kubernetes on private cloud?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

**Jenkins Service File**

```
{ apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: jenkins
spec: 
  ports: 
     - port: 8080
       protocol: TCP
       targetPort: 8080
       nodePort: 30000
  externalIPs:
     - A.B.C.D
  selector: 
    app: jenkins
  type: NodePort
 }
```

**Background:**
I want to access dashboard on Kubernetes, this service is running on Kubernetes cluster, I cant find more documentation about how to access the jenkins dashboard.
- Do I need more configuration in the service file?
- Are there any alternatives or way to accomplish this?

Comment: you should be able to access the dashboard on nodePort 30000 on any kubernetes host IP

Comment: @Prabhjot Kaur, Have you reached dashboard on the `nodePort`  30000?

Comment: @IjazKhan  I can't access it.

Comment: @mk_sta No, the dashboard is not accessible.

Comment: @Prabhjot Kaur, Can you share your Ingress configuration?